# What is Kitty mode on Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

What does the *kitty mode* do in Google Colaboratory?
Seen in the Miscellaneous page in the preferences dialog (accessible from `Tools > Preferences`).

[image: preferences with kitty mode]

Comment: This much you could've explored yourself. Try unchecking or checking one or both 'Corgi and Kitty Mode options. Basically, these modes add some animated fun to your notebook

Answer (score 21):

The kitty mode setting adds animated Kitties in the header.

https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1148286772863856642

[image: kitty mode header]